# Quadratic and arithmetic mean inequality

Tags: inequality, induction

I want to prove by induction that

$$\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k\right)^2\leq\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2$$

But I have no idea how. For n=1 it is trivial that
$$\left(\tfrac{1}{1}\sum_{k=1}^{1} x_k\right)^2\leq\tfrac{1}{1}\sum_{k=1}^{1} x_k^2=x_k^2$$

But if i want to conclude n+1 from n I get

$$\left(\tfrac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k\right)^2\leq\tfrac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k^2$$

And now I cannot seperate $\tfrac{1}{n+1}$ in order to substitute the rest with the induction hypothesis.

Maybe one needs to use a different version of induction? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Forward-Backward induction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/forward-backwards-induction/) that is used to prove AM-GM? Apply similar ideas here.

Answer (score 2):

With a little rewriting, the Induction hypothesis is
$$\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^2 \leqslant n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}$$

For the inductive step, note
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k +x_{n+1} \right)^2 = \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right)^2} + 2x_{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right)+x_{n+1}^2  \color{blue}{ \leqslant n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2} + x_{n+1}^2 + 2x_{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right)$$

Hence it remains to show
$$2x_{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right) \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2+nx_{n+1}^2 \iff \sum_{k=1}^n \left(x_{n+1}-x_k \right)^2 \geqslant 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

you can resolve the $1/n+1$ hurdle by considering *weighted averages* of previous $n$ points and new added one.

Then consider that $f(x)=x^2$ is convex